# Highlight href Lightning Community page in a Lightning Tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-tab

I am trying to add a Lightning Tab component to several custom Lightning Community pages and have the corresponding tab highlighted for the page it is on. Example: If I I am on the Home page I want the Home tab to be highlighted, if I am on the Overview page I want the Overview tab highlighted and so on.

---

For a lightning:tabset where do I specify the href for the corresponding page for each tab?

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<div class="demo-only" style="height:10rem">
    <lightning:tabset>
        <lightning:tab label="1st tab" onactive="{!c.loadFirstTab}" id="One">
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="2nd tab" onactive="{!c.loadSecondTab}" id="Two">
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</div>
```

JS:

```
({
loadFirstTab : function(component, event, helper) {
// do whatever you want
},
loadSecondTab : function(component, event, helper) {
// do whatever you want
},
selectedTab : function(component, event, helper) { 
component.find("tabSet").set("v.selectedTabId", tabId);
},
```

})

Comment: a quick tip, instead of adding, removing classes, you can use the Toggle method from the $A.util class

Comment: additionally, any reason you are not using the lightning:tabset component?

Comment: See the changes above. Thanks for the pointer on tabset. how do I specify what page to load with the corresponding tab?

Answer (score 3):

If you go through the attributes of the component, you might notice that selectedTabId allows you to do this.

> Allows you to set a specific tab to open by default. If this attribute is not used, the first tab opens by default.

[lightning:tabset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tabset.htm)

Ex:

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:tabset aura:id="tabSet" selectedTabId="one">
        <lightning:tab label="Item One" id="one">
          Sample Content One
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Item Two" id="two">
          Sample Content Two
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
selectedTab : function(component, event, helper) { 

    /*set the tab id you want based on your logic*/

    component.find("tabSet").set("v.selectedTabId", tabId);
},
```

Comment: Getting there :) Thanks for the help. Where and how do I specify the actual page to load on the selected tab. The selected tab is now indeed the highlighted tab but the selected tab is just that and does not open the page it should.

Comment: please dont follow up in the comments with code, not fery user fiendly. Better if you open a new post with your current code and what doesnt seem to work. tHx!

Comment: Yeah I am a novice. :(

Comment: you'll get the hang of it =P

Comment: Ok updated the original. Where and how do I specify the actual page to load on the selected tab? The selected tab is now indeed the highlighted tab but the selected tab is just that and does not open the page it should.

Comment: Still looking for this last piece. The selected tab focus is working great. Where do I specify what actual custom community page to open with each tab?

Comment: not ure what you mean by "specified page to  load"? you usually insert lightning components in each tab

Comment: I have 7 custom pages that I have placed this Lightning Tab component on (think of it as a subtab component to the default Lightning Community nav component). It sits on the Content Header of the page. My desire is that the 7 tabs I have open the 7 pages I have. Each page is a custom Lightning Community page with URL ending in /s/ask-ac-1, /s/ask-ac-2 etc. Does this make sense? The reason I am using a custom Lightning Tabs component and not the standard Tabs component offered in the Community Builder is so I can have a different layout per page, thus needing the Tabs cmp to change the page.

Comment: you can't really put a page in the above lightning tab component, it has to be a lgihtning component =/, thus, if you have 7 different pages, you cant really have the lightning tab component manage your page redirection/navigation, you would need a custom navigation component for that. If you want to display different content within the tabs above, then you can either add the component within it dynamically or code it in the markup. (unless i missunderstand your post) - I would suggest you open a new post, and include screenshots in order to provide better assistancec.